# Generate listview dynamically from ajax - refresh not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to generate a listview dynamically with jquery mobile. I have this code but the .listview('refresh') is not working:

```
<div id="content" data-role="content">       
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "my.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(articles) {
            var html = '<ul id="hellolist" data-role="listview"><li><h3>One</h3></li><li><h3>Two</h3></li><li><h3>Three</h3></li></ul>';            
            $('#content').append($(html));
            $('#hellolist').listview('refresh');
        }                            
    });
</script>
```

If I generate only the list items or I don't use ajax the refresh formats the listview well.

test #1: it works well.

```
<div id="content" data-role="content">
    <ul id="hellolist" data-role="listview"> </ul>
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        var html = '<li><h3>One</h3></li><li><h3>Two</h3></li><li><h3>Three</h3></li>';            
        $('#hellolist').append($(html));
        $('#hellolist').listview('refresh');
</script>
```

test #2: it works well.

```
<div id="content" data-role="content">       
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        var html = '<ul id="hellolist" data-role="listview"><li><h3>One</h3></li><li><h3>Two</h3></li><li><h3>Three</h3></li></ul>';            
        $('#content').append($(html));
        $('#hellolist').listview('refresh');
</script>
```

test #3: it works well.

```
<div id="content" data-role="content">
    <ul id="hellolist" data-role="listview"> </ul>       
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "my.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(articles) {
            var html = '<li><h3>One</h3></li><li><h3>Two</h3></li><li><h3>Three</h3></li>';            
            $('#hellolist').append($(html));
            $('#hellolist').listview('refresh');
        }                            
    });
</script>
```

Anybody has any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the empty UL tag in the HTML, you can try calling the .trigger('create") method instead of .listview("refresh");

If that doesn't work, try just calling .listview(); without the "refresh" param.

So, basically, instead of

```
$('#hellolist').listview('refresh');
```

try

```
$('#hellolist').trigger('create');
```

or

```
$('#hellolist').listview();
```

Good luck.

Edit: If things still aren't working, you might instead try triggering the create event on the page containing the new list.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working of the first because you're append the UL tag as well.
Try to append ONLY the 'LI' tags, the UL should already be in the html structure.

```
var html = '<li><h3>One</h3></li><li><h3>Two</h3></li><li><h3>Three</h3></li>';
```

In your html:

```
   <ul data-role="listview" id="" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="a" ></ul>
```

Comment: I think he knows it works like that. See the test 3 from the post.  The point is, if I am understanding correctly, he wants the ul to be added dynamically.